# Explanation on Django's request processing - Why does it select one urlpattern from another

Tags: python, html, css, django

So I am doing an free online course that involves Django and have run into something that is rather confusing regarding how Django processes requests. My Django application has a single module and within this module I have essentially two pages that I am generating both of which inherit from a layout template. There is an index page (which contains links to individual entries) and an entry page which displays the content of each individual entry. There are two ways to get to an entry page. You could either directly click on the link that is present on the index page or you could type in the search bar that is present on index page. If the name matches the entry in the search bar it will take you to that entry page. Each method of reaching an entry page has its own url pattern in the urls.py file and each one has its own route function in the views.py file. What was happening was that regardless of what was typed into the search bar, it would only use the route that was meant for directly clicking on the entry link from the index page rather than the route that was meant for searching. Here are my html files:

layout (contains the nav bar for searching:

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                <h2>Wiki</h2>
                <form action="{% url 'encyc:search' %}" method="GET">
                    <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
                </form>
                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'encyc:index' %}">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Create New Page
                </div>
                <div>
                    Random Page
                </div>
                {% block nav %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="main col-lg-10 col-md-9">
                {% block body %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

index page:

```html
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>All Pages</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'encyc:display' entry %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

and the entry page:

```html
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    {{ name }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    {{ entry | safe }}

{% endblock %}
```

Here is my urls.py file:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "encyc"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    # variable names for each page
    path("<str:name>", views.display, name="display"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search")
]
```

Here is my views.py file:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
import markdown2
from . import util
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='encyclopedia/log.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)

def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })

def display(request, name):
    logging.debug('request info: ')
    logging.debug(request)
    logging.debug('request path info: ')
    logging.debug(request.path_info)
    # convert name to all lowercase and then capitalize
    entry = util.get_entry(name.lower().capitalize())
    if (entry != None):
        entry = markdown2.markdown(entry)
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
        "name": name,
        "entry": entry
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")

def search(request):
    logging.debug('request info: ')
    logging.debug(request)
    logging.debug('request path info: ')
    logging.debug(request.path_info)
    name = request.GET['q'].lower().capitalize()
    entry = util.get_entry(name)
    entry = markdown2.markdown(entry)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
        "name": name,
        "entry": entry
    })
```

Here is the urls.py file for the entire Django application:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("encyclopedia.urls")),
    path('wiki/', include("encyclopedia.urls"))
]
```

Ultimately the fix here was in my urls.py file for individual module. The line

```
path("<str:name>", views.display, name="display")
```

should have been

```
path("wiki/<str:name>", views.display, name="display")
```

This began my quest to understand what was happening and why that worked. After digging into [Django's documentation on request processing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path_info), it appears as if Django takes a request, scans the url patterns, and picks the first match based on a 'path_info' attribute. So now I know that the reason it was only using the display route rather than the search route is that it was somehow matching this attribute to that route and was never actually reaching the search urlpattern. This begs the question of why was it matching based on 'path_info'. I decided to set up a logger and take a look at what the request info was and the path_info. Here is a log for before the fix was implemented:

```
DEBUG:root:<WSGIRequest: GET '/CSS'>
DEBUG:root:request path info: 
DEBUG:root:/CSS
DEBUG:root:request info: 
DEBUG:root:<WSGIRequest: GET '/search?q=css'>
DEBUG:root:request path info: 
DEBUG:root:/search
```

and here is the log after the fix was implemented

```
DEBUG:root:request info: 
DEBUG:root:<WSGIRequest: GET '/wiki/CSS'>
DEBUG:root:request path info: 
DEBUG:root:/wiki/CSS
DEBUG:root:request info: 
DEBUG:root:<WSGIRequest: GET '/search?q=css'>
DEBUG:root:request path info: 
DEBUG:root:/search
```

It appears to me that the path info is nothing more than the route that was specified in the url pattern. I still don't see why this fix works. Why does prepending 'wiki/' to my display route urlpattern allow for Django to now properly match the path_info when it couldn't before. Another question is why doesn't Django use the name attribute that was specified in the urlpattern to match the desired route? I specified in the html that I wanted the url for 'search' but it still selected the url for 'display'. If it were to just match the name that I had provided shouldn't this clear any ambiguity in selecting the appropriate url? I know this is a long winded post but any insight into how Django is processing these requests and why this specific fix worked for me would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 2 steps need to be seperated:

1. rendering ot the {% url  .... %} tag in the html which leads to the final url in the page
2. dispatching the request when the user clicks on the url
   Both is linked to urls.py->path

Ad 1)  for the display hrefs your urls is "reverse" created according to the name "display" and the attribute which you also called "name" in the path match string. So {% url "display" "css" %} leads to  "server_name/css".
The search field does exactly the same via the path definition with the name"="search".
So everything is ok up to this point  You see the correctly created urls/requests in your DEBUG data.

Ad 2) upon a request django gets only the url called and goes step by step through all your path statements to find a match.
Here is your problem because your patterns are not unique:

```
path("<str:name>",  ....
```

will match /css  but also  /search?... because str matches any following string including "search?...".

You need to first to choose the target and then give the parameter like

```
Path("display/<str:parameter>" .....
Path("search" ...   )
```

Then search is not matched by the preceding display path anymore.